# How to use a template to render Taxonomy within Shape Layout Projection items?

Tags: orchardcms

I have a Projection with a Query that has a 3-column Layout, and each of the items (of Content Type 'Artware') renders correctly, including showing the Taxonomy. Now I create a second layout using a Shape Layout, with a Display Type 'Gallery'. In the template I use this:

```
<div class="span8 gallery-background">
<ul id="isotope-container" class="clearfix">
    @foreach (dynamic shape in buildShapes())
    {
        <li class="@classes">
            @Display(shape)
        </li>
    }
</ul>
</div>
```

and then I create another template called 'Content-Artware.Gallery' to render each of the Artware shapes. This also works as expected when I'm accessing properties such as the image URL, title, etc.. However, when I want to render nested shapes, such as the Taxonomy, the only way I can see to do it is like this:

```
IEnumerable<TermPart> termParts = Model.ContentItem.Artware.ProductType.Terms;
string terms = string.Join(",", termParts.Select(t => t.Path));
```

But I would prefer to display the Taxonomy (and other sub-parts) using a template @Display(taxonomy). How do I do this?

If I look at the Shape Tracer there is no structure on the left under Content in the LightboxIsotope collection, even though a Taxonomy shape is shown in the Model on the right.

[image: Trace of Gallery Projection]

By the way `@Display(Model.Taxonomy)` displays nothing.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Taxonomy is not a shape, but you can create a shape and set the terms as one of its properties: @Display.MyTermsShape(TermPaths: termParts.Select(t => t.Path)) or something like that.

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy I assumed that becasue Taxonomy was listed as a 'Shape' on the rhs in the shape trace above, it was one. So if it is not then I should implement a template 'MyTermsShape.cshtml', in your example?

Comment: Well, yes, you are right, there is also a taxonomy shape. You can place it using placement.info, and then you can override its rendering by copying and modifying taxonomy.cshtml from the module to your theme.

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy ro anyone else, Can you point to example of how to display a taxonomy. Not a term but a complete taxonomy, in a Widget, in V1.7?

Comment: Yes: the existing taxonomy.cshtml. Am I missing something?